# Entity Framework Authentication Provider - Update Default Connection

Tags: .net, entity-framework, database-connection, connection-string

I've moved my .mdf to the production sql server database but when I update my "defaultconnection" connection string the authentication provider throws an error.  My connection string is `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication1-20181218212041;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication1-20181218212041.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

This has to be an easy fix.  Can someone let me know what needs to be here now that I have moved the production database to my production sql. This is NOT SQLExpress.  Thanks!

Comment: And what is the error you have? I think you're using wrong parameter or MDF-related issue, it's hard to guess the cause without error details.

Comment: you should chck the connection string in the production server it usually is different from your local machines connectionstrng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then your `ConnectionString` should be as like as follows:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source= YourServerName\YourSqlServerInstanceName;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;User Id=YourUsername;
Password=YourPassword; providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: This is great and fixed my problem - thank you!  I tried this last night but must have had something small off in the connection.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Great to see that your problem has been fixed! Welcome!